# Google Chrome always searches using top bar

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

My home PC, Windows 10, latest Chrome, using Google as a default search. Whenever I search for something, the typing is done in the top bar (URL bar) instead of the Google Chrome search bar even if I put the cursor inside Google's search box. Why?

I didn't see this issue on my other laptops.

So basically I want to search using google's search box like this:

[image: Google search box]

But instead I'm being forced to type in the address bar like below, even if my cursor is inside the search bar.

[image: Google Chrome URL bar]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what is the "google chrome search bar"? Can you provide a screenshot? Stock Google Chrome only has a single "Omni-box" - there is no separate "search bar". Are you referring to the search box on the "new tab" page? Or the Google website search page?

Comment: @w3dk I updated the question

Comment: That behaviour does seem bizarre. I've only experienced this with the _search box_ on the "new tab" page, not on the Google website itself.

Comment: @w3dk when you open a new tab even if that new tab looks like this http://prntscr.com/c8hi3x ? and what about when you open the browser? can you type inside the search box?

Comment: @w3dk if I explicitly go to google.com, only then i can use the search box

Comment: "even if that new tab looks like this" - Yes, that looks like the standard "new tab" page to me and yes, clicking in _that_ search box always directs focus to Chrome's Omni-box (address bar) - that has been standard behaviour for me (Chrome, Windows 7) for as long as I can remember. However, visiting the website itself (ie. http://www.google.com) - as you suggest - allows you to type in Google's search box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's by design. Chrome has worked that way for some time, now. I expect that they do this in order to illustrate that you can (and should) use the Chrome Omnibar for searching.

Comment: strange, this issue is only on one laptop. my work laptop doesn't have it neither my linux laptop. I don't know why one should use the omnibar though, but I don't have any options.

Comment: @Lynob What OS is your "work laptop"?

Comment: @w3dk windows 10 too, I don't remember what happens when i search in new tab, i'll have to test it  at the office but I'm pretty sure that when I start  the browser I see the same view as the new tab and I can type in the search box

Comment: "when I start the browser I see the same view as the new tab" - Yes, that will be the "new tab" page. (Unless you change this in settings for the browser to start on a specific page(s), or to "continue where you left off". Of course, you could change this to always start on the actual google.com home page, rather than the new tab page - both will show a similar search box.)